# how do I install twitter bootstrap rails 4 on just one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to add twitter bootstrap to just one page w/o changing the others?

When I use rails g bootstrap:install it changes my application.css and thus changes some of my other pages.

I thought I could use 
rails g bootstrap:install
rails g bootstrap:themed Blog
but it is making changes to my other pages like I said.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just manually add a css link tag pointing to your bootstrap file(s) on the page you need it on.

Answer (score 0):

rails g bootstrap:install will place the bootstrap relative files into the assets pipeline which will make it available in all pages.

You can just download the bootstrap relative file into the public folder and make a css link in the page you need.